# Impute Invalid Values

Tags: c#

I have some invalid date values in my data.I want to impute invalid date values with a valid date,what will be the best algorithm to do so?
for e.g

```
Date 
--------------------
Day/Month/Year
2/15/2001
Missing-Value
3/-1/1999
32/2/1998
-1/2/2007
1/1/-1999
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTime.TryParse()`. You can then check if the date was valid or not.

```
string dateString = "32/11/2013";
DateTime date = new DateTime();
if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out date))
{
    date = myDefaultDate; //replace the invalid date with a default one
    //or with the current date
    //date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); 
}
```

Comment: After that how will i replace that invalid data?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the part of the date that is invalid or how to replace the entire invalid date?

Comment: after checking that i want to replace that invalid date with a valid date...

Comment: Does work only in regions where `/` is used as date separator.

Comment: If you want the replace the entire date, see my answer. If you want to replace only the date part that is invalid (e.g. a day that's 32) you need to split the date into its components and individually check them for correctness.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, what do you mean? Doesn't it automatically detect the format, as in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
List<string> your_input_dates = new List<string>();
DateTime temp_date;
foreach (var date in your_input_dates) {
    var date_valid = DateTime.TryParse(date, out temp_date)
    if (date_valid)
    // do something with valid date, using temp_date variable
    else
    // do something else, prompt for error, or just continue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention how you are going to find a valid date from invalid one. So, I just replaced the invalid ones with current time.

```
var list = new List<string>
               {
                   "11-03-2013",
                   "11-03-2013",
                   "11-03-2013",
                   "11-04-2013",
                   "11-04-2013",
                   "11-04-2013"
               };

DateTime d;
IEnumerable<string> valid = list.Select(s => DateTime.TryParse(s, out d) ? s : DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```